# How to disable the 'Cc', 'Assign to' and 'Keywords' - fields from the "new ticket" form in Trac?

Tags: trac

Just want to simplify the form.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the ticket template (/usr/share/pyshared/trac/ticket/templates/ticket.html on Debian-based systems) directly.  I have made the following changes in our Trac installation.

```diff
--- a/trunk/trac/usr-share-pyshared-trac-ticket-templates-ticket.html
+++ b/trunk/trac/usr-share-pyshared-trac-ticket-templates-ticket.html
@@ -266,5 +266,7 @@
                   </tr>
                 </py:if>
-                <tr py:for="row in group(fields, 2, lambda f: f.type != 'textarea')"
+
+                <!--! Do not show Remaining or Owner field when creating a ticket. -->
+                <tr py:for="row in group(filter(lambda f: ticket.exists or f.name != 'owner' and f.name != 'estimatedhours',fields), 2, lambda f: f.type != 'textarea')"
                     py:if="can_modify or can_create"
                     py:with="fullrow = len(row) == 1">
```

as well as putting the Description field first (but that is a longer story).

Comment: Ideally, you should override the template, instead of changing Trac's core template files. To do that, just copy the original ``ticket.html`` to the ``templates`` directory of your trac environment and change it to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

You want the [Simple Ticket Plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SimpleTicketPlugin).  I'm not sure if it works with 0.12 or not since the tags for it only go through 0.11, but it's worth trying.